# android studio how set layout gone

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout

In my application, I set my LinearLayout "ln_invite" visibility to show, and I want to gone show the Frame layout when recycleview is empty...
how I can add this to my java file please?

xml:this is the entire xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".menu.ChatsFragment">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="718dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ln_invite"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="your list is empty"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="please add to fesTurn "/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

this my java I want make layout "gone" if my rcycleview is empty

java:this is the entire java code

```
package com.example.liorsivan.menu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.liorsivan.R;
import com.example.liorsivan.model.Chatlist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    public ChatFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private List<Chatlist> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


        getChatList();
        return  view;
    }

    private void getChatList() {
     //   list.add(new Chatlist("1","Lion sultan" , "I waiting for you", "01/09/2020","https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/150x100q90/924/cDpcz3.png"));
       // list.add(new Chatlist("2","Ofir iskovich" , "work hard play hard ", "01/09/2020","https://i.ibb.co/D15gkwV/pp-1.jpg"));
      //  list.add(new Chatlist("3","Sivan Aronashvili" , "This my app", "01/09/2020","https://i.ibb.co/LCTGvwJ/pp-3.jpg"));
      //  list.add(new Chatlist("4","hila amar" , "Lior is my king !", "01/09/2020","https://i.ibb.co/Cn0q26Q/pp-2.jpg"));
      //  recyclerView.setAdapter(new ChatListAdapter(list,getContext()));
        if (list.isEmpty())
        {
           
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
...
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    public ChatFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private List<Chatlist> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        linearlayout = view.findViewById(R.id.ln_invite);


        getChatList();
        return  view;
    }

    private void getChatList() {
     //   list.add(new Chatlist("1","Lion sultan" , "I waiting for you", "01/09/2020","https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/150x100q90/924/cDpcz3.png"));
       // list.add(new Chatlist("2","Ofir iskovich" , "work hard play hard ", "01/09/2020","https://i.ibb.co/D15gkwV/pp-1.jpg"));
      //  list.add(new Chatlist("3","Sivan Aronashvili" , "This my app", "01/09/2020","https://i.ibb.co/LCTGvwJ/pp-3.jpg"));
      //  list.add(new Chatlist("4","hila amar" , "Lior is my king !", "01/09/2020","https://i.ibb.co/Cn0q26Q/pp-2.jpg"));
      //  recyclerView.setAdapter(new ChatListAdapter(list,getContext()));
        if (list.isEmpty())
        {
           linearlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

To change a view's visibility, you can call:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```